# how to control the one whole class by onclick event of another class?

Tags: jquery

I am using the spritespin plugin. Please see this link - http://spritespin.ginie.eu/examples.html

Wherever the action like mouseup, mouse down action in spritespin class takes place it will rotate 360 degree

I don't want this action.

I am in need of action to be control by another class.

```
<div class="spritespin"></div>
<div class="left-mov"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="right-mov"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Here i want to control the spritespin whole action by mouseover action of left-mov or right-mov class.

How can i proceed this ?

any idea, please guide me....

```
/* original code starts */
$(".spritespin").spritespin({
     width: 609,
     height: 503,
     frames: frames.length,
     behavior: "hold", // "hold"
     module: "360",
     sense: 1,
     source: frames,
     animate: false,
     loop: false,
     loopFrame: 0,
     frameWrap: false,
     frameStep: 1,
     frameTime: 72,
     enableCanvas: true,
     reverse: false,
     orientation: 'horizontal'
 }).bind("onFrame mouseup mousedown onLoad", function (e) {
     ----------------------------
 });

 /* original code ends */

 /* my code have to start like this */
 $(".left-mov a, .spritespin").mouseover(function (e) {

     // here i dont know how to bind the sprintespin class action, guide me please urgent....

 });
 /* my code ends */
```

Comment: [I threw something together for you](http://jsfiddle.net/jmedP/). Basically what I've done here is made an object with some properties, after testing it, the speed seems to work at around 35 MS, so I used that value. I bind the mouseovers and use setIntervals to determine how long often we should move frames. Let me know if this is good enough for you and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: you are using bind function . remove binding on mouseup , mousedown and then trye Jai's Snippet

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks jee for your effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $(".left-mov a").mouseover(function (e) {
      $(".spritespin").spritespin("prev");         
 });
```

if required for next:

```
 $(".right-mov a").mouseover(function (e) {
      $(".spritespin").spritespin("next");         
 });
```

You can read more here: http://spritespin.ginie.eu/examples/api-usage

Comment: If i am using this then i am getting this type of error:    TypeError: data.module.reload is not a function
data.module.reload(data);